# Caffe matlab examples for training and testing CNN

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

How can I train and test a CNN using Matlab? 
Can anybody give me an example code?

Comment: Hi, did you find something?

Comment: can anybody give me code? hello Stackoverflow is not giving you code... It is for what code you have tried by your self... and If there is issue in that code.

Answer (score 1):

you can find Matlab examples in the Caffe repository: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/matlab

Comment: There is only one. Where could one find more like in the examples folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple tutorial. it contains sample code
https://ahmedibrahimvt.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/caffe-in-matlab-matcaffe-simple-tutorial/